# Fetch multiple row output from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch multiple rows output I know it can be done easily with while loop but my problem is that if I will use while loop the title of corresponding row will come. I just don't want to change the title but want to change the content. Here is simple data what I want

```
    tableA

    id                title                            msg

    1                 eeee                              frrffrfrrfrr
    2                 vvfdfd                           ffvfvdfvddd
    3                 vffdcadvg                         fdfvddfgvre
    4                 dfdf                              fvvvf
```

So if I will use while loop then title of that row will also come so I just want to keep changing the row['message'] value. My simple MySQL query is

```
   $res = mysql_query("select * from tableA");
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    $msg=$row['msg']
```

As you can see it will easily display title and message for corresponding row but I want title of one row and message output of 4 rows how it can be done?

Comment: So you want msg and title for the first row and only msg for subsequent rows? Not sure if I fully understand.

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated , avoid them

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop:

```
$res = mysql_query("select * from tableA");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo $row['msg'];
}
```

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Why you're using `mysql_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc`?